# Read / Write only own records on Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I am rather lost with Firestore Rules.

I want authenticated users to be able to read their own records, but cannot manage to achieve that. I am writing the userId into each record. When reading, I expect the user will get all records where field `userId == request.auth.uid` Here is my code from the Firestore console:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /{document=**} {
          allow read: if resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
      }
  }
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  } 
}
```

Writing is OK, but with reading I get "missing or insufficient permissions" exception in my app. I checked that `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()` is returning a value matching to my `userId` field.

Comment: can you post the query you use to make the request to the database?

Comment: Quite simple, FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("docs").get()

Answer (score 3):

According to [Todd Kerpelman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47579966/1477950)
Cloud Firestore doesn't have the time to search through every record in your database to ensure that your user has access, so it will reject this query. Instead, you'd need to run a query where Cloud Firestore can "prove" that all documents you'd retrieve will be valid.

**Solution:**

Try with this query, specifying that you want to receive only the user's documents:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("docs").whereEqualTo("userId", uid )
```

where uid is the uid of your auth user:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.getUid()
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the immediate problem for me. Do you have any reference to a Firebase source to understand how this works? I have several queries, and it seems a bit too cumbersome to need to fit them so that they don't ask for parts of data that could be restricted...

Comment: Good :) Your question was similar to mine https://stackoverflow.com/a/47579966/1477950 i edited my answer!